# python - kivy: error: Failed building wheel for kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Estoy tratando de instalar kivy y tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi SO es W7 64 bits

Mi versión de python es 3.6 (32 bits)

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el error  `Failed building wheel for kivy` se muestra como consecuencia a la excepción presentada mas abajo en tu captura. El problema es que no se pudo hacer el decode del caracter 0xe1 que corresponde a la letra "á" en tu user de Windows (Familia Bazán). Podrías probar simplemente a cambiar el nombre de tu usuario en Windows de modo que la carpeta no tenga un caracter latino en su nombre. O podrías trabajar desde otro usuario en el sistema. El punto es que debes evitar esa clase de caracteres especiales en la ruta de instalación para evitar esa excepción.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba descargandote directamente el archivo binario (wheel), es decir la libreria ya compilada para tu sistema usando uno de los siguientes enlaces dependiendo de tu versión de Python:

- [Python 3.6 - 64 bits](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/tuoh5y4k/Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl)
- [Python 3.6 - 32 bits](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/tuoh5y4k/Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl).

Dices que tu sistema es de 64 pero la versión de Python (32 o 64 bits) no lo dices. Si tienes dudas abre el intérprete interactivo y arriba te muestra si es de  64 o 32 bits.

Una vez descargado instalalo usando:

`py -3.6 -m pip install ruta_del_archivo.whl`

Para simplificarlo te puedes ir a la carpeta de descarga y en la barra de direcciones del Explorer lo borras todo y pones `cmd` y pulsa <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Esto lanzará la consola en el directorio actual y solo necesitarás algo como:

Versión de 64 bits:

`py -3.6 -m pip install Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

o para la version de 32 bits:

`py -3.6 -m pip install Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`

Los enlaces pertenecen a la [página](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) de Christoph Gohlkede la Universidad de California que proporciona binarios actualizados para Windows de los paquetes más importantes de Python. Dejo la página porque los enlace del principio pueden variar con el tiempo.

Prueba esto a ver si el problema aparece asi también o no. Kivy tiene problemas con el compilador MinGW en Windows para versiones de Python >= 3.5 por lo que para evitarse problemas al instalar via pip es mejor usar los binarios directamente.